# How to create and fill php array from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have MYSQL table:

```
|column1|column2|column3|
|id1    |human1 |data   |
|id2    |human1 |wejkls |
|id3    |human2 |sklkls |
|id4    |human1 |sdasds |
|id5    |human2 |l;lkls |
|id6    |human3 |kkklkl |
|.......|.......|.......|
|idN    |human..|.......|
```

So, I need to create php array:

```
Array {
[1] => human1
[2] => human2
[3] => human3
[N] => humanN
}
```

And how can I get names of persons and fill them array?

---

**Added**: Now I have this code:

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "password", "db");
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `teacher` FROM school_year ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while ($a[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {}
print_r($a);
```

print_r result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Ahmed A.A.) [1] => Array ( [0] => Scott P.P. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => ....)...
```

How to get names as values in array? I don't need to print names, I need them for other function.

Comment: What have you tried in order to achieve this? - This is very basic php / db interaction and there are a dozen of tutorials out there that shows you how to do this.

Comment: Get some lessons about _select query in php_

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT `... the rest you gotta do own your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)**

**Example #1 Fetch all remaining rows in a result set**

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column2) as human FROM tablename ORDER BY column2 ASC;
```

This will give you all humans one time no matter how many entries for each human exist.

Alternative:

```
SELECT columns2 as human FROM tablename GROUP BY columns2 ORDER BY column2 ASC
```

From there it depends on your implementation in PHP itself, e.g. if you use PDO or mysqli or a library.