# Need to fill PHP Array when I use MysqliDb.php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using below admin pannel:
https://github.com/harsh4870/phpcoreadmin

I have below code in the form (\forms\customer_form.php) where I can see static array ( `<?php $opt_arr = array("India", "Middle East", "Nepal", "South Indian"); ?>`), I would like to replace this static array to be picked from the MySql database (Table name: CUSTOMER| Column_name: STATE).

Thanks in advance

```html
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>State</label>
    <?php $opt_arr = array("Maharashtra", "Kerala", "Madhya pradesh"); ?>
    <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
        <option value=" ">Please select your state</option>
        <?php
        foreach ($opt_arr as $opt) {
            if ($edit && $opt == $customer['state']) {
                $sel = 'selected';
            } else {
                $sel = '';
            }
            echo '<option value="'.$opt.'"' . $sel . '>' . $opt . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: If you just go through some PHP + MySQL tutorials (there are thousands of guides if you just do a quick google search), you should be able to figure it out quite easily. At least enough to make some attempts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create and fill php array from Mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343345/how-to-create-and-fill-php-array-from-mysql-database)

Comment: Didnt work.....

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to start a MySQL connection and then submit a query.

Here's a quote from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).

> The SELECT statement is used to select data from one or more tables:
>
> `SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name`
>
> or we can use the * character to select ALL columns from a table:
>
> `SELECT * FROM table_name`

Below is an example.

```
<?php
// Connection Info
$host = "localhost";
$user = "myuser";
$pass = "mypass";
$db = "mydb";

// Start Connection
$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

// Check Connection
if ($link->connect_error) {
  // Error Handler
  die("MySQL Connection Error: ".$link->connect_error);
}

// Prepare Query
$query = "SELECT 'AREA_NAME' FROM 'REIGONAL_AREA'";

// Submit Query
$result = $link->query($query);

// Check for Errors
if ($result) {
  // Set counter
  $i = 0;
  // Set data variable
  $opt_arr = [];
  // Loop through data
  while($current = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output[$i] = $current[0];
    $i++;
  }
?>
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Header Elements Go Here -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>State</label>
  <?php $opt_arr = array("Maharashtra", "Kerala", "Madhya pradesh"); ?>
  <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
    <option value=" ">Please select your state</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($opt_arr as $opt) {
      if ($edit && $opt == $customer['state']) {
        $sel = 'selected';
      } else {
        $sel = '';
      }
      echo '<option value="'.$opt.'"' . $sel . '>' . $opt . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
} else {
  // Error Handler
  die("MySQL Error: ".$link->error);
}
?>
```

Comment: There are some issues with this code. 1. You define `$opt_arr` before the loop and are using that in the HTML, but you never add anything to it. You're adding to `$output`, which you never define or use later on. 2. The array should be defined before of the `if`-statement, or you'll get an error when trying to use it if no records was found. 3. You're getting the row with `fetch_assoc()`, which means that `$current[0]` won't work. It needs to be: `$current['AREA_NAME']`. 4. There's no need to manually add the array index (using `$i`). Just do: `$output[] = $current['AREA_NAME'];`.